# Running sequelize init returns error

Tags: orm, sequelize.js

I have sequelize installed through npm but when I try to run sequelize init, I get bash: sequelize: command not found. What could be the possible issue. I am trying to start a project based on this guide: [Angular Project with Sequelize orm and NodeJS](https://scotch.io/tutorials/creating-an-angularjs-application-with-sequelize-part-1)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try installing it using

```
npm install -g sequelize-cli
```